# How do I draw line with TikZ showing 3 point A,B.C?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a line showing end points A and B with a Point C between using TikZ.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome! There are lots of questions about this. Next time, please try something out and post the code you come up with so that you can ask about a specific problem you are having.

Here's one way:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=1.5pt] (0,0) node [fill, label=below:A] {} -- +(1,0) node [midway, label=below:C, fill] {} node [fill, label=below:B] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: ACB]